# How to access two dimension array in MEL : mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, payload, mule-component

How to access two dimensions array in payload MEL format
I have this data in datamapper
for ex: I have following payload

```
ID  NAME    TEST    Source
1   name1   test1   ABC
2   name2   test2   XYZ
3   name3   test3   sourceVal
4   name4   test4   TTT
```

I want to get `sourceVal` value. How can I get in payload as two dimension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that your payload is a List of Maps the following MEL expression should get the Source value for the first element.

```
payload[0]['Source']
```

If your payload is just a simple two dimensional array you can use

```
payload[0][3]
```

Comment: Ok.. That means if i need sourceVal then i have to write payload[2]['Source'] .. instead of index i also use column name right??

Comment: It all depends on how (what java objects) your two dimensional array is stored in the message. If it is a List of Maps, which would be my guess since that is the most common output from the datamapper, then the first index indicates the row (note that this is the index in the list not the Id value) and the second will look up a specific field in that row.

Comment: You wrote payload[0]['Source'] for first element that means  Is it return ABC ??

Comment: Correct if the payload is a List of Maps as I described earlier.